# update and sanitize a value of a select field

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to update and sanitize the value of a select field, this custom field is in user-edit-php
I,m using this code

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'saldo', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['saldo'] ) );
```

But it doesnt work. The values of the option are correclty printed on the posts, but the seletion doesnt stay visible after editing
Maybe have I to update and sanitize each option of selector? How can I fix this code?